# Clipboard copy paste not working for firefox using selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having a link on clicking which it copies text to clipboard.
On manual execution it is able to copy to clipboard and thus fetch it, using webdriver for firefox it is not able to copy the text to clipboard.
Tried same with Chrome, it is working fine. 
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Actions objActions = new Actions(objDriver);
objActions.moveToElement(actionCopyScript).click().build().perform();    
strScript = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
            .getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Comment: How do you know, that the text hasn't been copied to clipboard ? Are you pasting the contents somewhere ?

Comment: Yeah i am pasting the copied text in a file. It is working fine with Chrome, but don't know why it is pasting the last manually copied text to file when i use firefox.

Comment: I tried something in Google.com, like: Entered a text in the search field, Selected, and Copied it (using Selenium) and then pasted the contents of Clipboard. **ALL USING FIREFOXDRIVER AND THE LAST PART OF YOUR ABOVE CODE**. It gave me the correct output. So, It works in Firefox. I would suggest you to modify the locator (xpath/id) you are using to click on the element(that results in copying of data in clipboard) and try again

Comment: Actually i am not copying a text visible in UI. On clicking the link the server is hit which generates a code script and is then copied to clipboard which has attribute clip-copy=getTextToCopy(product).

Comment: After clicking on the element (that performs the copying of text to clipboard). Give some sleep time of 5-6 seconds. Probably the code script is not getting copied into clipboard and needs some time.

Answer (score 0):

Other than question, please do let us know some basic info (code u tried, which langague) etc..

Assuming it's Java, it should work with the following lines...

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
StringSelection str = new StringSelection(copyTo);
clipboard.setContents(str, null );
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: I have added code of fetching code from clipboard in the question. Its pretty astonishing that data is being copied to clipboard using chrome but not using Firefox.

Comment: and wont your code set the clipboard contents to an empty string?

Comment: can u check replacing the following StringSelection str = new StringSelection(new String(""));